# Тэг <a> размножился на странице. Шаблонизатор Blade (Laravel)

Tags: php, html5, laravel, blade

у меня есть исходный код для шаблона, что-то похожее:

```
<div class="panel-box">
    <div class="title">Фильтер</div>
    <ul class="panel left menu-list">
        <form ajax-action="{{ route('search') }}" id="filter-form">
            @foreach($data['features'] as $feature)
            <li>
                <a>
                    <span class="name">{{ $feature->name }}</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>

                    <ul class="drop-panel lmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">{{$feature->slug}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </form>
    </ul>
</div>
```

После открытия страницы в инспекторе обнаруживаю вот такое:

```
<div class="panel-box">
    <div class="title">Фильтер</div>
    <ul class="panel left menu-list">
        <form ajax-action="http://local.dev.eurolight.com/search" id="filter-form">
            <li class="active">
                <a>
                    <span class="name">Цвет плафона</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="drop-panel lmenu">
                    <a></a> <!-- Вот этого не должно быть -->
                    <li>
                        <a></a> <!-- Вот этого не должно быть -->
                        <a href="#">cvet-plafona</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <span class="name">Кол-во источников света</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="drop-panel lmenu">
                    <a></a> <!-- Вот этого не должно быть -->
                    <li>
                        <a></a> <!-- Вот этого не должно быть -->
                        <a href="#">kol-vo-istochnikov-sveta</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <span class="name">Тип лампочки</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="drop-panel lmenu">
                    <a></a> <!-- Вот этого не должно быть -->
                    <li>
                        <a></a> <!-- Вот этого не должно быть -->
                        <a href="#">tip-lampochki</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>                
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <span class="name">Тип крепления</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="drop-panel lmenu">
                    <a></a> <!-- Вот этого не должно быть -->
                    <li>
                        <a></a> <!-- Вот этого не должно быть -->
                        <a href="#">tip-krepleniya</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </form>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Вот у меня и вопрос: с чем это может быть связанным?

Comment: возможно на какой-то итерации перебора в {{$feature->slug}} попадает пустая строка. Проверьте полученный вами массив, все ли данные в нем присутствуют.

Comment: Я тестил 3 варианта тегов: <div>, <span>, <a> - и такое происходит конкретно с <a>, по итерациям я проверял - все нормально, там не может быть пустой строки.
И присмотритесь к коду с инспектора, я пометил комментариями что там не должно быть, а по итогу имеется.

Comment: а лишний тэг попадает только в инспектор браузера или в html код страницы тоже?

Comment: и в html код тоже

Comment: Самое интересное: точно такая же структура, но немного другого направления работает нормально. Т.е. такого бага нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена!
Заключалась она в том, что я немного неправильную структуру сделал.
Вот правильная структура. Но я до сих пор не понимаю почему прошлая ломалась?

```
...
            <form ajax-action="{{ route('search') }}" id="filter-form">
                <div class="panel-box">
                    <div class="title">Фильтер</div>
                    <ul class="panel left menu-list">
                        @foreach($data['features'] as $feature)
                        <li>
                            <a>
                                <span class="name">{{ $feature->name }}</span>
                                <span class="arrow"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="drop-panel lmenu">
                                <li>
                                    <a>a</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </form>
...
```